# What is the impact coming from wildcard %

Tags: sql-server

I need to add a new SELECT statement whose search condition include something like **leagueCode LIKE 'nba%'**.

I would like to know if the index against leagueCode is still exploitable or introduce any overhead after % is included in the target column.

Comment: Do you mean: ` leagueCode like 'nba%' `?
Otherwise you're not doing a wildcard search at all, you looking for the literal characters 'nba[percent character]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it depends 100% on the position of the wildcard.

- At the beginning: no index. Some servers have inverse indices (starting at the end of the string) and would use them - SQL Server does not.
- In the middle: Partial index (beginning part), then seeking within that range.
- in the end: Index (Acutally an INDEX SEEK will be shown in the query analyzer).

Overhead? Sure - but it is not exactly high (no table scan) and there is not exactly a way to work around it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the index can still be used because you have a constant prefix (`nba` in this case).